# Ubuntu VNC Access Through Port

Tags: ssh, remote-access, remote-desktop

I am trying to access an Ubuntu machine remotely though "Remote Desktop Viewer". Usually I access it through a series of terminal ssh connections like:

1 - Network 1:

ssh user@newtwork1

2 -  Network 2:

ssh -p 2222 user@network2

3 - Ubuntu Machine :

ssh user@IP

This works fine, but I was wondering how to do this using a remote desktop application like "Remote Desktop Viewer" or Remmina.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh in through Remote Desktop Viewer, by launching from your desktop and changing the drop-down that reads VNC to SSH. Then simply put your user name and host in the appropriate fields.